# can asp.net mvc can auto generate timestamp to js code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

We have a problem: anytime we deploy a new version

cache must be cleared on every browser to refresh the js and css code.

Is there any built-in tool to generate a unique timestamp in the js name?

**update1**

I tried to bundle my js, but yet no stamp is auto generated

bundles:

```
   `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/abTestingAdmin").Include( "~/Scripts/abTestingAdmin.js"));`
```

aspx:

`<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/bundles/abTestingAdmin") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`

from the browser console

`<script src="/bundles/abTestingAdmin" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8316991/425003

Comment: You can use bundling for this. EDIT: Exactly as Icarus said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you register your CSS files and your JS files using Bundles ([full example here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)), both types of files will be minified, combined and a unique URL parameter will be added automatically when you deploy your app so that browsers are forced to grab it again.

Comment: did bundle, but not stamp is autoGenerated: `<script src="/bundles/abTestingAdmin" type="text/javascript"></script>`