# How to cache in asp.net webpages

Tags: asp.net, caching, razor, asp.net-webpages

can anyone please assist or point me to a resource on caching in asp.net webpages using razor or so? I'll like to cache some css and js files. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers automatically cache .css and .js files, so don't worry about that.

What you should consider is how can you force a browser to do a GET if changes are made to the .js or .css files?Luckily there are many resources on the web that can help you, e.g - [Force browsers to get latest js and css files in asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185872/force-browsers-to-get-latest-js-and-css-files-in-asp-net-application)